# SELECT CASE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am running a simple query having `SELECT CASE`

```
SELECT DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME = 
    CASE DEPT_NAME
        WHEN 'PBG' THEN 'Best Dept'
        ELSE 'Usual Dept'
    END
FROM DEPARTMENTS;
```

However, the output is not satisfactory. All `0` is coming in output

[image]

**What is wrong in query ?**

Otherwise the table has below data

```
SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the column alias `DEPT_NAME`. It should be placed after the `case` expression, not before:

```
SELECT DEPT_ID, 
    CASE DEPT_NAME
        WHEN 'PBG' THEN 'Best Dept'
        ELSE 'Usual Dept'
    END as DEPT_NAME 
FROM DEPARTMENTS;
```

Comment: Great. (Did you perhaps use SQL Server specific syntax?)